# Validating using JavaScript - how to show to all validation error message's

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have function that checks if fields are blank but if all fields are blank it only shows one of the validation message's, I think this is because I have used an if statement:

```
          function validateForm()
        {
         var sName=document.forms["myForm"]["surname_5"].value;
         if (sName==null || sName=="")
       {
           document.getElementById("sNameMessage").innerHTML = "*Surname is required";
           return false;
       }
          var x=document.forms["myForm"]["firstname_4"].value;
           if (x==null || x=="")
        {
          document.getElementById("fNameMessage").innerHTML = "*First name is required";
          return false;
        }
       var y=document.forms["myForm"]["selectid"];
         if(y.options[y.selectedIndex].value == "Title")
       {
      document.getElementById("titleMessage").innerHTML = "You need to select a title";
      return false;
      }


      }
```

How do I get it so all validation messages show if the user has left all fields blank?

Answer (score 3):

Don't return `false` immediately. Set a variable to `false` (after defining it as `true` at the very start of the function) and return that variable at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (or add all your code if you need more details)

**JavaScript:**

```
function validateForm() {
    var sName = document.forms["myForm"]["surname_5"].value;
    var ret = true;
    if (sName == null || sName == "") {
        document.getElementById("sNameMessage").innerHTML = "*Surname is required";
        ret = false;
     }
     var x = document.forms["myForm"]["firstname_4"].value;
     if (x == null || x == "") {
         document.getElementById("fNameMessage").innerHTML = "*First name is required";
         ret = false;
     }
     var y = document.forms["myForm"]["selectid"];
     if (y.options[y.selectedIndex].value == "Title") {
         document.getElementById("titleMessage").innerHTML = "You need to select a title";
         ret = false;
     }
     return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it does show the messages for a second but then post's back to the server?

Comment: I don't understand your comment this is a question or an affirmation ? and please add some code if you want help.

Comment: Your solution is not fully working, as it shows the message's but than post's back to the server anyway. Should I change this onsubmit="validateForm(); return false;?